# Error with pathway_errorbar function in ggpicrust2 package: "legend.text.align" not defined

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm encountering an error while trying to use the pathway_errorbar function from the ggpicrust2 package in RStudio. The function is supposed to visualize the results of my functional pathway differential abundance analyses, but I'm getting an error related to legend.text.align. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
Error in `plot_theme()`:
! The `legend.text.align` theme element is not defined in the element
  hierarchy.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─patchwork:::print.patchwork(x)
  3.   └─patchwork:::build_patchwork(plot, plot$layout$guides %||% "auto")
  4.     └─base::lapply(x$plots, plot_table, guides = guides)
  5.       ├─patchwork (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
  6.       └─patchwork:::plot_table.ggplot(X[[i]], ...)
  7.         └─ggplot2::ggplotGrob(x)
  8.           ├─ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))
  9.           └─ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built(ggplot_build(x))
 10.             └─ggplot2:::plot_theme(plot)
 11.               └─ggplot2:::validate_theme(theme)
 12.                 └─base::mapply(...)
 13.                   └─ggplot2 (local) `<fn>`(...)
 14.                     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 15.                       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

And this is the code (adapted from https://github.com/cafferychen777/ggpicrust2):

```
ggpicrust2::pathway_errorbar(abundance = kegg_abundance,
                             daa_results_df = daa_annotated_sub_method_results_df,
                             Group = metadata$treatment,
                             ko_to_kegg = TRUE,
                             p_values_threshold = 0.05,
                             order = "pathway_class",
                             select = test[1:10],
                             p_value_bar = TRUE,
                             colors = NULL,
                             x_lab = "pathway_name")
```

I've tried using the example dataset provided in the documentation of the pathway_errorbar function, but the same error persists. It seems like there might be an incompatibility issue between ggplot2 and ggprism. In an effort to troubleshoot, I've removed all ggprism related code from the pathway_errorbar function. While this does result in a plot being generated, the differential abundance data remains invisible, which leads me to question whether the data is being calculated correctly. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ggprism has a theme saved to disk, including theme elements that have been deprecated. Because of this saving, the theme never goes through the `theme()` function where the deprecation is handled.

We can simulate that error message as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  (theme() + list(legend.text.align = "left"))

p
#> Error in `plot_theme()`:
#> ! The `legend.text.align` theme element is not defined in the element
#>   hierarchy.
```

I'd recommend just explicitly removing the offending theme element by assigning `NULL` to it.

```
p$theme$legend.text.align <- NULL

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-12 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response, yet it still does not solve my problem. Indeed when I run your code it does work, and the plot is made. But when I use the pathway_errorbar function from ggpicrust2, it still does not solve the problem and I get the same error.